# Very slow bootup time after adding SSD - Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, performance, raid

I wanted to increase the speed of my DLL PC so added a new 120 GB SSD hard disk in addition to the previously present hard disk, system boot up time became very slow.

It is litreally  stuck at bios boot up blinks for a long time, reboots itself about 2 times and only then the windows loader appears. Once the windows loader appear,things are faster.

Please note that 2 * 250 GB hard disk was configured in RAID mode which came along with the Pc. I ensured cleared all data, formatted the OS and installed freshly Windows 10 in SSD drive (non partitioned). Other hard disks drive partitioned to 3 drives.

Right now bootup takes around 20 minutes every time.

Config: DELL PC
RAM: 8GB DDR2
CPU: i3 processor
Only OS : Windows 10 (no dual boot options)

Kindly help me here on how to fix this as i am facing this problem for about months.

Comment: Did you check for firmware updates from Dell yet? Unfortunately, from my experience, Dell firmware is abysmally slow. Of course, that’s only like 30 seconds, not 20 minutes.

Comment: If your computer is rebooting itself there are other problems going on, and while the SSD may be a contributing factor, it is likely not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Disconnect all drives but the new SSD, does it boot properly now?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it needs a bios update, not compatible, or not set up correctly with it being stuck on bios for so long. Needs possibly a lot of testing me thinks.

Comment: The Dell tool analyzed my PC and tried to update latest bios firmware but failed to complete due to some errors.

Comment: Also, I tried to unplug the Old Hard disks and boot only via SSD problem still persists. Please check my connection of wires as below. https://photos.app.goo.gl/fSd1tRpwk51Kknb6A

Comment: Below is the screen I am stuck with https://photos.app.goo.gl/8c3nt22igDm2wbWs9